# jQuery menu with click to show and hide on mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At the moment it shows the divs instead of hiding them and on click it hides just so you can see the movement. Should be .show instead of .hide. On clicking the link, li should slide down and on mouseleave slide back up.

Working example http://jsfiddle.net/DTqDD/3/

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
     var toggleMenu = function(e) {
         var self = $(this),
             elemType = self[0].tagName.toLowerCase(),
             //get caller
             menu = null;
         if (elemType === 'a') {
             //anchor clicked, nav back to containing ul
             menu = self.parents('ul').not('ul#mainmenu');
         } else if (elemType === 'ul') {
             //mouseleft ul, ergo menu is this.
             menu = self;
         }
         if (menu) {
             menu.hide('medium');
         }
         e.preventDefault();
         return false;
     };

    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('a.drop').click(function(e) {
             $('li#mainmenudrop').show('medium');
             console.log('div clicked');
             e.preventDefault();
             return false;
         });
         $('li#mainmenudrop a').click(toggleMenu);
         $('li#mainmenudrop').mouseleave(toggleMenu);
     });
 });
```

Comment: and what distracts you from doing this?

Comment: You have invalid markup in the fiddle, duplicated `mainmenudrop` IDs are invalid html.

Comment: so i would have to script each li with a diffrent script? updated it a litlle

Comment: so really all you are trying to do is on click show an element and then on the mouse leave of the element you want to hide an element ye?

Comment: yes thats it, hmmm just by you saying that understanding it all the better

Comment: updated... it works when using ul as the item to be dropped but not when you want li to drop. http://jsfiddle.net/DTqDD/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `li` tags change `id="mainmenudrop"` to `class="mainmenudrop"` since it ain't valid HTML. Then use the following jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('a.drop').click(function(e) {
         $(this).next("div").show('medium');
         console.log('div clicked');
         e.preventDefault();
         return false;
     });
    $('li.mainmenudrop').mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).children("div").hide('medium');
    });
});​
```

Could this possibly be what you are trying to accomplish?

**EDIT:**
If you want the divs hidden at the beginning, just add this CSS:

```
.mainmenudrop div {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: hopefully loading it up now been up all night trying!

Comment: Yes, it's javascript error on your code. You don't need the top part anymore. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/RRJjf/

Comment: lol its so late hmm early tried all the options apart from none. yep sure that will do it. just hope it works when i attacht the script to the more detailed menu. is there an need for the var function in this? or can it be done without? http://jsfiddle.net/bLmwm/7/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DTqDD/8/ - done works in fiddle! just need to make it work in code - thanks specur. might get to bed sometime today!

Comment: Awesome! :) Remember that if you change the HTML structure, you might have to edit those selectors in the javascript.

Comment: lovely worked a charm, only thing is that the hover over function still works but after a few secs the script takes over, think it has to do with the time it takes to ready the scripts before you start interacting with the menu. when mouse is removed it seems like there is no slide to the menu (again seems like css hover) www.apecharmony.co.uk/more_info_domains.php . only TRINITY has been set so far.

Also you cleaned that up a lot. thank you. Do i need to put in var functions for this menu or can it be done as you have just done : jsfiddle.net/bLmwm/7

Comment: It should be able to be done as I mentioned earlier (without your var function). On your website the menu uses CSS hover and it conflicts with the javascript menu method. I believe that's why it's not functioning properly. The conflicting CSS is located in `css/menus.css`. (The script is basicly overwriting the CSS hover method after the javascript has fully loaded.)

Comment: will remove the hover function... but thee is a lot tied to it will have to look into it...., on the second menu could only adapt the script to open the menu the mouseleave function is different...

Comment: manage to remove the delay by display:none with the div, but this doesnt solve the menu closing without slide